# Tasks for a particular planID and assigned to me

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

1. If I use `tasks`, I see only tasks assigned to me and then I can switch to different plans if needed = all is good.
2. If use parameter `targetID`, `tasks targetId="{PLANID}"`, I can target a particlar plan - this also works, all is good

My requirement is to show tasks assigned to me in a particular plan. Is there a way to force this on first load?

For now, I am using `TargetID` attribute. However, that shows all the tasks from that plan, even if they are not assigned to me.

Referred to properties from here, no luck  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/tasks

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a great candidate for a feature-suggestion on our repo, there isn't really a way to retemplate this since you'll need the "me" or user as well. Some attribute like "my-tasks-only" so we filter tasks based on id would be best, I don't think the Graph will be able to handle this. If you make an issue on our repo with these details, it'll help move this feature [request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Needs%3A+Triage+%3Amag%3A%2C+feature-request&template=feature_request.md&title=) along!

Comment: Sure. I have created this feature request here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/1302